# Java program Calendar view Datebook

Tags: java, class, calendar, arrayobject

I am working on an assignment where i have to create Event class and then put random events in an array of Event type(array object). I was able to solve that problem but now i have to display the whole month just like below. So if there is any event on a day, an asterisk will be printed next to it. This is not a GUI assignment. This is just a simple assignment. The assignment asks me this:

> A calendar view, listing the days of the week (Sunday to Saturday) horizontally across the top, and the days of the month underneath. Next to each day where there is a scheduled event, print an asterisk "*". Like in a real calendar, the first day of the month can be any of the weekdays.

```
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
     1   2*  3   4   5   6  
 7   8   9  10  11* 12* 13  
14* 15* 16* 17  18  19* 20  
21  22  23  24  25* 26* 27  
28* 29  30
```

Can anyone give me some hints as to how i can proceed? I just need some kind of idea of how to start coding for the Calendar View. Right now, i don't have any idea of my one. Anything that would start me off would be appreciated. If anyone wants to look at my Event class code the here it is.

```
class Event{
/*** Instance variables ***/
  private String timeofEvent;
  private String nameofEvent;
  private int priority;

/*** Constructor***/
  public Event(String timeofEvent, String nameOfEvent, int priority) {
    this.timeofEvent = timeofEvent;
    this.nameofEvent = nameofEvent;
    this.priority = priority;
 }
/*** Instance methods ***/
  public String nameEvent(){
    return nameofEvent;
 }
  public String timeEvent(){
    return timeofEvent;
}
  public int priorityEvent(){
    return priority;
}
  public String toString() {
    return timeofEvent + ":" + nameofEvent + "(" + priority + ")";
}
}
```

I would gladly explain the problem if anyone needs more explanation. There is more code but i just don't want to paste the whole thing as someone might plagiarize it.
**We are not allowed to use calendar class.**

Answer (score 0):

I've got an idea. If you aren't working with GUIs, perhaps you could just print out a calendar to the terminal. If you wish to do so, I would let each column in a 2D array have 5 spaces in it. That way, for the top of the calendar, you could have the Strings look like " Sun "" Mon "... without the quotes.If there's no space between them, it'll look jumbled together. Then, a number inserted into the array at the proper location would need to equal 5 spaces overall, also. Such as: "  1  ""  2  " or " 29  "" 30  " or " 29* "" 30* ". If you fill the array with all the correct strings(don't forget the asterisks), then simply print it all out at the end. To fill the array, you would need a for loop that can figure out when to print day number 1(in case it's on Mon or Tue and so on) and when to stop(since months have different numbers of days). A few ints and booleans should do the trick.